# Index Access for Calculating Hamming Distance

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql, oracle11g, query-performance

I have a table populated with strings in a database column. I am computing the Hamming Distance of the column with a binded variable and then, using a separate statement, outputting all the string values with, say, a Hamming Distance less than or equal to 3.

Since the string value is binded, I am unable to use a virtual column on the desired results, since as far as I know, that requires the function to have static parameters. Also, I cannot use a function-based index because my output is a derived column.

Is there an alternative solution to optimizing the query without performing a full table scan? Currently the scan takes 5-7 seconds and I would like to reduce this to 300 ms. Thank you.

Here is some of the source code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HAMMING_DIS(string1 IN varchar2, string2 IN varchar2)
RETURN number IS
distance number := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR counter IN 1..length(string1) LOOP
      IF substr(string1, counter, 1) = substr(string2, counter, 1) THEN
        distance:= distance + 1;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
RETURN distance;
END;

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT FULL_NM AS FULL_NAME, HAMMING_DIS(FIRST_NM,'&A') AS HAMMING_DISTANCE 
 FROM STRINGS_OF_NAMES
 )
WHERE HAMMING_DISTANCE > 3;
```

Comment: What exactly are you comparing?  A column with a variable?  A column with every other instance of that column?  Also, can you give us some information about the values?  Do they always have the same length?  If not then I assume the function or query needs to throw out values with different lengths.  Is the "less than or equal to 3" static, or do you want to compare different values?

Comment: Do you use a PL/SQL function to calculate the Hamming Distance ? If yes, then please show a soruce code of this function. Could be that you are affected mainly by a SQL-PL/SQL context switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification... I'll delete my other answer.

If... and these are big ifs...

- A) You always want to find strings with Hamming distance < 3 (e.g. not <3 sometimes and <5 other times) and
- B) Your table is *static* enough to allow the use of `BITMAP` indexes,

then you can maybe take advantage of the fact that any answer to your query has to have at least 2 matches in the first 4 characters.

So,

```
CREATE TABLE matt1 ( id number, str varchar(30) );

INSERT INTO matt1 SELECT rownum, dbms_random.string('U', dbms_random.value(1,30)) from dual connect by rownum <= 10000;

CREATE BITMAP INDEX i1 ON matt1 ( substr(rpad(str,4,' '),1,1) );
CREATE BITMAP INDEX i2 ON matt1 ( substr(rpad(str,4,' '),2,1) );
CREATE BITMAP INDEX i3 ON matt1 ( substr(rpad(str,4,' '),3,1) );
CREATE BITMAP INDEX i4 ON matt1 ( substr(rpad(str,4,' '),4,1) );


SELECT m.*, hamming_dis(str,:input) FROM matt1 m WHERE 
(
(substr(rpad(str,4,' '),1,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),1,1) AND 
substr(rpad(str,4,' '),2,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),2,1))
OR
(substr(rpad(str,4,' '),1,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),1,1) AND 
substr(rpad(str,4,' '),3,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),3,1))
OR
(substr(rpad(str,4,' '),1,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),1,1) AND 
substr(rpad(str,4,' '),4,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),4,1))
OR
(substr(rpad(str,4,' '),2,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),2,1) AND 
substr(rpad(str,4,' '),3,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),3,1))
OR
(substr(rpad(str,4,' '),2,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),2,1) AND 
substr(rpad(str,4,' '),4,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),4,1))
OR
(substr(rpad(str,4,' '),3,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),3,1) AND 
substr(rpad(str,4,' '),4,1) = substr(rpad(:input,4,' '),4,1))
)
AND hamming_dis(str,:input) <= 3;
```

You should see an execution plan with lots of `BITMAP OR` and `BITMAP AND` operations.

This could be faster because you'll be limiting the number of rows on which you'll actually need to compute the exact Hamming distance.

NOTE: I see that you wanted <=3, not <3.  The approach should be extensible up to a point.